# Decimal point number rounding to integer in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

I am a fusion applications developer and recently I have faced a strange issue with one of the client's production environment. There is a field in the UI which takes decimal point values as input like '0.01'. Its stored in DB in NUMBER datatype column. In the EO and VO, it is given 'BigDecimal' datatype...but when client enters a value like 0.01 from UI and inserts this record (on saving), this column value is changing to '1'. There is no way this should happen and I scanned the code for such change but there is none...please help me how to debug this, as it is client's PROD environment, my options are limited.

Thanks

Comment: Code please? (jsf fragment, bean if used, model, db)

Comment: Does the same happen when entering 0,01? If yes, check the Locale settings

Comment: But how does locale settings effect this...@User404

Comment: @User404 How does locale settings impact this?

Comment: @User404: Thank you so much , that helped to resolve the issue.